# How do I use more then one pattern for gmatch

Tags: lua

Hello I am trying to get some data from a text file and put it into a table.
Im not sure how to add more then one pattern while also doing what I want, I know this pattern by its self %a+ finds letters and %b{} finds brackets, but I am not sure how to combine them together so that I find the letters as a key and the brackets as a value and have them be put into a table that I could use.

text file :

```
left = {{0,63},{16,63},{32,63},{48,63}}
right = {{0,21},{16,21},{32,21},{48,21}}
up = {{0,42},{16,42},{32,42},{48,42}}
down = {{0,0},{16,0},{32,0},{48,0}}
```

code:

```
local function get_animations(file_path)
local animation_table = {}
local file = io.open(file_path,"r")
local contents = file:read("*a")
for k, v in string.gmatch(contents, ("(%a+)=(%b{})")) do -- A gets words and %b{} finds brackets
    animation_table[k] = v
    print("key : " .. k.. " Value : ".. v)
  end
file:close()
```

end

get_animations("Sprites/Player/MainPlayer.txt")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid Lua code, why not simply execute it?

```
left = {{0,63},{16,63},{32,63},{48,63}}
right = {{0,21},{16,21},{32,21},{48,21}}
up = {{0,42},{16,42},{32,42},{48,42}}
down = {{0,0},{16,0},{32,0},{48,0}}
```

If you don't want the data in globals, use the string library to turn it into

```
return {
    left = {{0,63},{16,63},{32,63},{48,63}},
    right = {{0,21},{16,21},{32,21},{48,21}},
    up = {{0,42},{16,42},{32,42},{48,42}},
    down = {{0,0},{16,0},{32,0},{48,0}},
}
```

befor you execute it.

If you insist on parsing that file you can use a something like this for each line:

```
local line = "left = {{0,63},{16,63},{32,63},{48,63}}"
print(line:match("^%w+"))
for num1, num2 in a:gmatch("(%d+),(%d+)") do
  print(num1, num2)
end
```

This should be enough to get you started. Of course you wouldn't print those values but put them into a table.

Comment: I agree with you I could leave it like that, but I wanted to make it so I dont have to hard code the animations in my game, my plan is to have a sprite sheet (currently player) and a text file that includes the animations x and y cords and simply put them into a table and access them that way, so If in the future I wanted a different player sprite or say a sprite sheet has the sprites in different places this would make it easier to get the correct animations.

Comment: text files are always hardcoded. instead of having some text file that you need to parse you could simply have a lua file that you execute. the only reason not to do it this way would be that you want to stop people from adding code to that file that would also be executed.

Comment: hmm, so to make sure I understand, instead of having it as a text file, I should make it a lua file, how would I access the lua file, is it the same as using require "animations", so I would have the left,right etc inside a lua file or more specifically in its own table that includes all the animations.